# 2FORMC DPDT Relay gets stuck in middle

Tags: current, relay

I'm trying to charge 3 batteries via 2x[RS3s](http://www.dualpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/RS3-insert.pdf) in parallel for charging the 12V batteries. 
I got in touch with manufacturer and said that they work well in parallel. 
The issue is, after couple times of using,  2 [relays](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/357/850-0210-1202016.pdf) which are controlling the supply voltages of each charger, gets stuck in between NO and NC. Tried brand new relays, it did the same. What would cause a relay to get stuck like that? Inrush current of chargers are 7.8A, did bunch of tests about it. Any opinions- suggestions would help. What am I doing wrong?

Coil voltage - Powered with 12V batteries ranges between 11V to 13.9V
Contact voltage - 208VAC
Continuous current draw from load(charger) - 2A
Inrush current (worst case) - 7.8A

Comment: Draw a circuit. Explain what stuck in between really means.

Comment: If you are using the 2 DPDT relays to switch 2 batteries from series to parallel and they are not matched voltage, the problem is not your charger inrush, but the contacts burning out from equalizing the voltage with low ESR batteries.